# Dynamic Tex editors?

Tags: miktex, editors

Are there dynamic Tex Editors that are like Overleaf that one can download and use? My idea is one that can allow me to write Tex Code, and just press a button and have compiled in a split-screen. Currently, I have MikTex, and it works but if anyone knows how to make it be like a split-screen and not a new window? I see under window ribbon that side by side option, but I believe it is not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question, but what is a split screen and how do you want to use it?

Comment: @AndréC A split screen is basically having one window open where the Tex editor is on the left, and PDF is on the right. Basically, as you would type it will update the right  PDF. Instead of having two windows open, and putting them side by side.

Comment: There is a long list of editors in the referenced question, but two popular ones that do have an embedded PDF viewer are TeXstudio and Texmaker. (One minor thing: I think when you're saying MikTeX you actually mean TeXworks. MikTeX is a collection of software, which includes a TeX editor (TeXworks).)